# Shared Preferences not getting right Default Value

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I made one class with name session and i maintain my all shared preferences from there only like..

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }
```

Now from UI application i call this session and my all variable didnt get there default value like..

```
public void setIsFirsTimeCall(boolean IsFirsTimeCall) {
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("IsFirsTimeCall", IsFirsTimeCall).commit();
        prefsCommit();
    }

    public boolean getIsFirsTimeCall() {
        return prefs.getBoolean("IsFirsTimeCall", true);
    }
```

so when i call for getIsFirsTimeCall() then it will give false to me

I don't know why it is doing this 
But when i copy and share this project to other PC then its work fine 
Have you ever seem this type of behavior

Comment: try uninstalling your app from the device/emulatir, and re-run it.

Comment: Did you try to use .apply() instead of .commit() ? Also, you can try to get the boolean return value of the commit() operation

Comment: remove common method to save and retrieve prefs, every time use a new editor when you commit.That helped me once

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko i did uninstall and also i changed workspace and try in another one in same PC but no success

Comment: @ValentinoS. when i call session constructor then only i found preferences object and mMap value is {AppTheme=1, RadioPOS=1, AppVersion=8, isPermissionIsGranted=true, IsFirsTimeCall=false}

Comment: I added an answer now, but I noticed that maybe is not what are you searching for. Did you try to do editor.clear(); before getting values the first time (only the first time)?

Comment: At the end i just change KEY for above functions for my project running but still in Map IsFirsTimeCall is loaded but now i am not going to be use this ID so this is the only my solution right now but still surprise with this annoying behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you to solve:

I think you can do something like this:

```
public static void setIsFirsTimeCall(Context cntx, boolean IsFirsTimeCall) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("IsFirsTimeCall", IsFirsTimeCall).commit();
    prefsCommit();
}

public static boolean getIsFirsTimeCall(Context cntx) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    return prefs.getBoolean("IsFirsTimeCall", true);
}
```

I've moved the declaration and definition of `prefs` from the constructor of `Session` class, inside each method that require it. Each of this methods is `static`, so you can call them from outside the `Session` class in this way: `Session.getIsFirsTimeCall(yourContext)` and so on.

Maybe you have to change the behavior of your code because I don't know if your method `prefsCommit()` can become `static`, otherwise you can't call it from a static method.

Hope it will help you